# how to remember the active menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with sub menu(vertical). My first `li` is active with the sub menu because i'm in the current page but My problem is when I hover in the next `li` I have the sub menu display it but if i lost the active `li` when i quits the menu

What I need is:

1. when my cursor is not hovering in my menu, i need the default sub menu that has the on class

This what i look do it 
[enter link description here](http://rcc.icpac.net/?sm_id=&tm_id=1&cdepth=2&upnum=1&ca_id=97&t1=1&s1=1)

this link of my code in FIDDLE
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/bymb6kvm/12/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bymb6kvm/13/ ?

Comment: Here you have the same effect without js: http://jsfiddle.net/bymb6kvm/14/

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your css so you don't need any js now.
It works this way:

> - In normal state an element with `.on` class is displayed;
> - When you hover #menu then we hide all the `.niveau2` elements
> - When you hover some tab then we show only its `.niveau2` element by adding an `!important` keyword to display property.

```
#menuu ul li:hover ul{
   display: inline-block !important;    
}

#menuu ul:hover .niveau2 {
    display: none;
}

#menuu .on {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is an example with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/bymb6kvm/14/